# Como pegar o body da requisição http na API

Tags: java, restful, resteasy

Como faço para acessar o conteúdo do body da requisição enviada pelo cliente? Por exemplo:

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("/mypath")
public Response myMethod() {
    System.out.println("Conteúdo da requisição: " + request.body);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Tenta colocar `@Context HttpServletRequest request` como parametro do método.

Comment: Até tentei, como vi em vários problemas parecidos. Só que o eclipse não consegue enxergar as referências e não reconhece a Classe. No fim, sempre dá `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest`

Comment: Até mesmo procurando pela classe (`Ctrl + T`) não consegue encontrar?

Comment: Infelizmente, não :(

Comment: O eclipse não tá fazendo `import` de nenhuma lib que venha da `javax.servlet.*`. Por algum motivo, não está reconhecendo.

Comment: Consegue adicionar dependências ao projeto? Tente inserir [essa](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/3.0.1).

Comment: O mais correto seria [essa](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) na verdade. Mas ai veja a sua necessidade.

Comment: A importação funcionou com a segunda referência, porém segui alguns links no SOen - [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24223657/5636215), por exemplo - não consegui retorno nenhum.

Comment: O request está carregado quanto entra no método?

Comment: @GustavoCinque, consegui resolver o problema somando a sua sugestão da lib com o que é citado [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31848289/5636215)

Comment: Legal, @HamurabiAraujo. Mesmo eu não entendendo como a solução de verificar se o método utilizado é `POST` ou não iria te ajudar. Mas mesmo assim, uma dica, a classe `javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod` mantem enums para os métodos mais comuns (`POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD` e `OPTIONS`). Vale a pena usar e não ter que fazer a comparação com string crua.

Comment: É porque realmente não faz sentido existir essa verificação. Agora que vc falou, que eu fui analisar direito (rsrs). Pois o método só aceita requisição `@POST`, então não há a menor necessidade de existir esse teste dentro do próprio método.